# Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute is not defined?

Tags: vb.net, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm attempting to create a new project similar to the SDK project basicoperations for Dynamics CRM 2011. I am using the myorganizationcrmsdktypes.vb file included with the SDK helper code, but when I attempt to build the code I get tons of errors in myorganizationcrmsdktypes.vb and I'm not sure why. The errors look like this:

```
Type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute' is not defined.
```

The code works fine when run in the original project, just not in mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk (/sdk/bin/microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll)

Also add another reference to: System.Runtime.Serialization

Additionally in your project settings - try clearing the Root namespace

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your code on a different machine?  This is less of a CRM issue and more of a .net issue.  If your vb project has a reference to the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` dll but yet your code can't find the classes within it, I'm almost wondering if something is corrupt.

I'd try recreating the solution / project.  I'd also try doing a `ctrl-.` (control period) to see if VS can resolve it for you...